# Header randomly inserted into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wampserver

I develop using under the WAMP / LAMP platform... specifically I'm using wampserver as my development environment. Recently I've experienced an issue whereby javascript functions fail to execute correctly. My javascript functions are held together in a file and included via the HTML header as follows:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{$wwwUrl}/js/include.js"></script>
```

When logging in to my app the password is md5 encrypted using a javascript function. All was working fine until recently, when the encryption seemed to stop working... The javascript console of my browser reported an error. When I viewed the javascript source a HTTP header seems to have been randomly inserted:

```
function isDateBefore(date1, date2) {
    date1Day   = date1.substring(8,10); 
    if (date1Day.substring(0,1) == '0') {
        date1Day = date1Day.substring(1,2);
    }
    date1Day = parseInt(date1Day);
    date1Month  = date1.substring(5,7);
    if (date1Month.substring(0,1) == '0') {
        date1Month = date1Month.substring(1,2);
    }
    date1Month = parseInt(date1Month);
    date1Year = parseInt(date1.substring(0,4));
    date2Day = date2.substring(8,10); 
    if (date2Day.substring(0,1) == '0') {
        date2Day = date2Day.substring(1,2);
    }
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 17:13:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.2.11
Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Mar 2015 20:04:50 GMT
ETag: "3c0000000bbc6e-5c36-51108c7a06712"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 23606
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/javascript

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}
```

I've no idea where the lines starting from `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` through to `Content-Type: application/javascript` have come from. Anyone able to shed any light on this?

Thanks,

Brian
http://www.rentpro.co.uk/

Comment: Thats messed up - this is happening on your local machine with a regular web browser? What browser/os/version?

Comment: The same thing happens when using Chrome / IE and FireFox. I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro

Comment: what do you get if you just download the file directly? (is the server adding the header or did you maybe accidentally paste/save it in there?)

Comment: Nope - the inserted lines are being added at run time..... I've some more info... I have two similar, but different applications, i.e. two completely different code bases and the same problem is experienced by both. I can therefore say with a fair degree of certainty that something has happened to my development environment, rather than an application issue. The issue first arose at the end of last week but performing a system restore seemed to rectify things. It then reoccurred a couple of days back. The common event to both was just after I had installed a HP printer driver....

Comment: I've uninstalled the driver but still no joy....